# Docker /tmp directory permission changed from 1777 to something different on RHEL 7

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rhel7

Recently there was some patching activity on RHEL 7 server managed by client and as a result the permissions of /tmp directory for Postgresql and MongoDB changed from 1777 to 775. I have no clue what caused this as the same container was working fine before the patching and I tried creating it multiple time but the permission was always set to 775.
After changing the permissions manually to 1777 for /tmp directory through custom Dockerfile things started to work.

Can someone please help with this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for _programming_ questions. You might want to explore our sibling site [unix.se], but please read their help pages before asking there (and please delete this off-topic post, and review our [help] before posting here again). They too will require more details, like where did you get the Docker image, what version of RHEL, what patches, etc.